# call external function from Yii controller

Tags: php, yii

I have an old php function in a .php files and want to include and call this from my controller.
I copy my .php function file to myLib folder first and then defined my function in config file like this:

```
// autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.myLib.*',
    ),
```

now how to call my function in controller??

I call it simple by name but I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function myFunction() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\protected\controllers\TestController.php on line 10

Comment: Where is the `myLib` folder located?

Comment: Inside protected folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yii autoloader is meant to load classes, as in, it will load the file for a class if the class is called. So this does not work for a singleton function in a file.

What you could do is make a helper class and add the function as a static method to the class.

for example :

```
class MyLib
{
    public static function myFunction()
    {
          //do stuff here
    }
}
```

and then you can just call out your function like you did before with

```
MyLib::myFunction();
```

Then store that class in the file /protected/helpers/MyLib.php

and in the config do:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.helpers.*',
),
```